# Symmetric difference of A and B

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In the two sets

$A = {\{1,2,3,4,5,6}\}$

$B = {\{1,3,9}\}$

Find the symmetric subtraction of those 2 sets.

Answer : $A \triangle B = (A \cup B) - (A \cap B)$ = ${\{1,2,3,4,5,6,9}\}- {\{1,3,9}\} = {\{2,4,5,6}\}$

Is it correct?

Comment: Thanks bjcolby15 for improving the question.

Comment: No problem!  You can edit the equations in MathJax using this guide...https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$9$ should not be in the intersection of $A$ and $B$ so it should be $\{2,4,5,6\}$